# string to byte[] to stream result Image is not complete

Tags: c#, arrays, string, stream, base64

I have images as string in Base64
i am trying to get these strings to an actual jpeg file

I used to get this error

Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

so I fixed it by adding this code

```
        temp_inBase64 = temp_inBase64.Replace(" ", "+");
        int mod4 = temp_inBase64.Length % 4;
        if (mod4 > 0)
        {
            temp_inBase64 += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
        }
```

now my final code is this
and I get just few lines from the image after that everything is greenish color

```
        string temp_inBase64 = @"/9j/4WX+RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAANAAABBAABAAAAwBQAAAEBBAABAA...";
        temp_inBase64 = temp_inBase64.Replace(" ", "+");
        int mod4 = temp_inBase64.Length % 4;
        if (mod4 > 0)
        {
            temp_inBase64 += new string('=', 4 - mod4);
        }

        byte[] temp_backToBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(temp_inBase64);
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\test\img.jpg", temp_backToBytes);
```

not sure what is wrong
I thought maybe string size cant take 10,000,000 char string but found that string variable can take more than 1,000,000,000 chars

any idea what went wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You could try UrlTokenDecode (because that is probably the "Base64" format you are trying to decode.

Comment: At least provide some test image in base-64 form, otherwise what can we tell? Also where do you get those images from and why you are sure they are valid?

Comment: @Evk images are 10MB of text and they have pics of our clients, cant post them :(

Comment: Ok, and why they are in base-64 in the first place? How do you know they are valid?

Comment: Just a heads up about my suggestion in the comment - turns out that method I suggested does not adhere to the Base64Url standard. Fire up google, there are probably better solutions (which are fully standard conform) on NuGet. Also - the question why it is Base64 in the first place is probably the first you should ask...I doubt you receive the content via URL....10MB can't possibly work by using the URL LOL

Comment: @Evk I joined the company they already Base64, cant answer your first question of why!  they work coz the images show in the website that was made to display clients info. my task is to convert these strings (varchar(max) in DB) to files

Comment: If the "encoding" side is in your company...it should be easy to figure out. While you are looking at that code....check if you could probably enhance the performance 4 times (transfer they bytes, omit the en/decoding). Update: Actually it would not be 4 times. It is early morning - forgive me. It would still save 1/3rd though.

Comment: Well, until you can post reproducable example (of base64 image) - I doubt anyone can provide much help. That image can be partially corrupted (browsers are quite liberal in rendering), but no way to know that without image in question.